# stat comand - compute difference of two timestamps

Tags: bash, timestamp, stat

I would like to compute the difference of two timestamps using a bash script: one which is the output of stat command and another one is defined as a string. The format of file timestamp is as follows:

```
2018-06-17 20:02:59
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: If you just want to find which file is older or newer, see the `-ot` and `-nt` comparisons in `man bash` (use `[[ ]]` with those).

Comment: try converting both timestamps to unix time and then just subtract (time2 - time1). This will produce time difference in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$(date -d '2018-06-17 20:12:59' +'%s') - $(date -d '2018-06-17 20:02:59' +'%s')" | bc
```

This will produce time difference in seconds.

Comment: Thanks. It will be helpful